# when I clicked on a link it doesn't go to the address

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I created this accordion. but when I open the accordion the hyper link www.facebook.com doesn't work or doesn't go to the hyper link.

first click on contact, an accordion will open. here is a link name www.facebook.com. When I click the www.facebook.com link it doesn't work or go to the href link.

Please give me solution.

```
[see this link][http://jsfiddle.net/o8d6574r/]
```

Comment: Your facebook link redirects to "fruit and vegetable" page. This is what you want?

Comment: @kamil when I click the link it doesn't redirect to the given link in href="". Please help me.

Comment: hmm it works fine for me. Clicked the link and redirected to `http://fruitenroute.com.au` as expected

Comment: but it not work for me....

Comment: would you like to update the fiddle.

Comment: I'm not sure what we need to update. Your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o8d6574r/) works fine.

Comment: did you click the link or open with right button?

Comment: Ok, i see the problem now. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: -1 Because instead of posting the code in your question, you hid the link to jsfiddle in a code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution. The problem was caused by `e.preventDefault();` added to your `.accordion` click function. Just delete it. I'm not sure why was it added there, but it blocks redirections from your links inside the `div`.

Here is the link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o8d6574r/6/)

Comment: it solved my redirect problem, but it created another problem. when I click on about tab it doesn't work properly. but first and last accordion are working well.

Comment: You have empty `href` there - `<a href="" class="accordionTitle">about</a>`. Just add `#` the same as on the other tabs. Result `<a href="#" class="accordionTitle">about</a>`. Link -> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o8d6574r/10/)

Comment: Thanks @Kamil. now it works. Many many thanks. you are a genius programmer. :)